No code returned after oauth2 dropbox library
I following the example from dropbox api
And I am stuck here:
//set credentials
const dropbox = dropboxV2Api.authenticate({
    client_id: 'APP_KEY',
    client_secret: 'APP_SECRET',
    redirect_uri: 'REDIRECT_URI',
    token_access_type: 'offline', // if you need an offline long-living refresh token
    state: 'OPTIONAL_STATE_VALUE'
});
//generate and visit authorization sevice
const authUrl = dropbox.generateAuthUrl();
//after redirection, you should receive code
dropbox.getToken(code, (err, result, response) => {
    // you are authorized now!
    //
    // ...then you can refresh your token! (flow for token_access_type='offline')
    dropbox.refreshToken(response.refresh_token, (err, result, response) => {
        //token is refreshed!
    });
});
//

What I get from this example is

ReferenceError: code is not defined

As I understand the code should be returned in the dropbox variable when I am authenticated in the previous rows. Do I make mistake somewhere ?

//after redirection, you should receive code - this seems to be missing a step, I don't think that const authUrl = dropbox.generateAuthUrl(); is actually doing any redirect, this just creates the auth dialog URL. You need to explicitly send the user to that URL.
